# I can't figure out how to do a switch in React with two components

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to switch between components on one file. I want the ShowAccount to be the default. A button to show EditAccount that would hide ShowAccount.

Mock-up of what I am thinking:

```
import React from 'react';
import EditAccount from './editacc';
import ShowAccount from './showacc';

const Toggle = () => {
    return(
        <>  
            if (EditAccount === Active) {
                hide <ShowAccount />
                show <EditAccount />
            } else {
                show <ShowAccount />
            }
        </>
    );
};

export default Toggle;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './acc.css';
import Header from '../../../Header';
import Toggle from './content/toggle';

const Myaccount = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <br />
      <Toggle />
    </>
  );
};
export default Myaccount;
```

Comment: That makes no sense at all. You have a conditional _statement_ in JSX, where you can only have _expressions_ (and even then they have to be wrapped in braces), you're comparing a component to the undefined variable Active, and you've randomly invented the show and hide operators.

Comment: I said it is a mock-up of what I am wanting it to do. Obviously, it's not going to work that way or it would... all i am saying is if one component is showing, I want the other one to be hidden. I did not intend for someone to think I was actually trying to do it this way. @jonrsharpe

Comment: I'd suggest you read e.g. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html, rather than just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handling using the state and render the conditional component.

```
import React from 'react';
import EditAccount from './editacc';
import ShowAccount from './showacc';

const Toggle = () => {
    const [isEditAccount, setEditAccount] = React.useState(false);
     
    const handleToggleView = () => {
       setEditAccount(!isEditAccount)
    };

    return ( 
      <>
      <button onClick={handleToggleView} >
       Toggle View
      </button>
      {isEditAccount ? <EditAccount /> : <ShowAccount />} 
      </>
    );
};

export default Toggle;
```

Answer (score -1):

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new?file=/src/App.js

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isAcc: true
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ isAcc: !this.state.isAcc })}>
          Toggle View
        </button>
        {this.state.isAcc ? <Acc /> : <Edit />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const Acc = () => <h1>Account</h1>;
const Edit = () => <h1>Edit</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```